# Does SimpleQrCode (php) support string concatenation?

Tags: php, laravel, qr-code, laravel-artisan

I'm using a [Simple QrCode](https://www.simplesoftware.io/#/docs/simple-qrcode) wrapper to generate qr codes for each location on the map.

I'm passing coordinates like this in locations.blade.php (I know this is not a good practice but this is for PoC purposes only):

`<td><a href="/qrcode?st_y=<?php echo $location->st_y; ?>&st_x=<?php echo $location->st_x;?>&naziv=<?php echo $location->ime;?>">Generiraj QR Kod</a></td>`

but when I try to edit the qrcode.blade.php like this (row 1 in the image):

`{!! QrCode::size(300)->generate('https://someurl.net/?lat=<?php echo doubleval(round($_GET['st_y'],2)); ?>&lng=<?php echo doubleval(round($_GET['st_x'],2)); ?>&zoom=17'); !!}`

QR code is not shown, but when I do it like this for testing (row 2 in the image):

`<p>{!! QrCode::size(300)->generate("https://someurl.net/?lat=45.1295437743251&lng=18.0378311714425&zoom=17") !!}</p>`

everything is fine.
[image]

I'm not really experienced in php and tried to dig something online, but unfortunately failed. [This](https://techvblogs.com/blog/generate-qr-code-laravel-8) is the tutorial I was following and it works fine, but the moment I want to introduce some variables to the link, it breaks. Any ideas?

Just a quick UPDATE:

when I copy the exact same output which is behaving wrong:

`{!! QrCode::size(500)->generate("https://someurl.net/?lat=45.1295437743251&lng=18.0378311714425&zoom=17"); !!}`

underneath qrcode that is behaving normally, everything is fine :/

UPDATE 2:
Here is an HTML to show the last case. This is really confusing.
[image]
[image]

Comment: *"nothing is shown"* can have many reasons. Do you have access to server logs? Apache's error log or the PHP log may have an error text for us. Keep in mind [round()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.round.php) already returns a float. doubleval() is an alias of floatval() so doesn't change a thing. Maybe use [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.number-format.php) to round like 6 decimal places?

Comment: Hello @PeterKrebs. Thanks for the comment. I have access to laravel, php, and apache logs but I don't see an error there. Regarding the formatting, these were just things I tried in despair since nothing seems to be working, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: If the logs also don't say anything there is not much to debug. You might want to `dd($location);` to see if it has the desired values. Otherwise good luck.

Comment: You can hit Ctrl+U in Chrome or Firefox to see the generated HTML. Compare the URL printed to the expected one.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I have updated my question but still don't get what's wrong. Do you see any anomalies?

Comment: You're mixing `{!! !!}` and `<?php echo ... ?>` tags. `{!! !!}` is basically shorthand for `<?php ... ?>`, so doubling-up on that will indeed break this. Correct syntax would be: `{!! QrCode::size(300)->generate('https://someurl.net/?lat=' . doubleval(round($_GET['st_y'],2)) . '&lng=' . doubleval(round($_GET['st_x'],2)) . '&zoom=17') !!}`. In Laravel, you shouldn't use `<?php ?>` tags _at all_; `{{ }}`, `{!! !!}` and `@php ... @endphp` are `.blade.php` Template tags that generates `<?php ... ?>` tags (with varying inner syntax) for you 

Comment: Wow, thank you @TimLewis!! Everything is working fine now! Will you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: You're quite welcome  I'm actually going to leave this as a comment, as this is essentially just a typo, and typo/syntax errors questions generally shouldn't be answered on Stackoverflow. I have voted to close as such (there's no downside to closed questions), but you're welcome to leave this question as a reference, or delete this questions. Cheers!